# Getting pagination data from an API response using python request library

Tags: python, api, python-requests, etl

Hi guys I am a python beginner I am trying to fetch all the information from an API whose responses are paginated.I am trying to get the "pagination data" so that I can use that to create my loop using request library.How can write the following shell command in python for me to get the desired results

```
curl -IXGET https://api.myapplication.com/products?page=1 -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <PRIVILEGED_ACCESS_TOKEN>" | grep X-Pagination

X-Pagination: {"total_records":3103,"total_pages":32,"first_page":true,"last_page":false,"out_of_bounds":false,"offset":0}
```

I tried doing this but am getting an error: `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'type'`

```py
import requests
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request

my_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 9YU5OXYdQlBXfROYAXrthdgqli8rkXMAnB5jEmkPZzE'}
pag_results = requests.get('https://api.myapplication.com/products?page=1,headers={"Content-type: application/json"}',headers=my_headers)
pagination_res1 = urlopen(pag_results)
pagination_res2 = pagination_res1.read()
print(pagination_res2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests

my_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 9YU5OXYdQlBXfROYAXrthdgqli8rkXMAnB5jEmkPZzE',
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}

page_num = 1
has_next = True

while has_next:
    response = requests.get(
        'https://api.myapplication.com/products?page=' + str(page_num),
        headers=my_headers
    ).json()
    has_next = page_num < response["X-Pagination"]["total_pages"]
    page_num += 1
```

You don't need to use both urllib and requests.
Here is what you need to do:

- Keep a counter i.e. page = 0
- Do a request to get data
- increase page by one
- if the page is less than the total pages from the response then do the request again

Comment: Thanks so much @nasir .Do you know why am getting error KeyError: 'X-Pagination' yet when print the header with print(response.headers)  I can actually  see the key exists

Comment: the print(response.headers) prints the key after removing the .json()

Comment: `response["X-Pagination"]["total_pages"]` should be based on your response,try printing the response first.